# change color of button in wpf C# after click and after 2 minutes retain the original color

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using this code

```
        Hello.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue;
        var dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(61);
        TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0,1,0);
        dispatcherTimer.Start(); 
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += delegate
        {

            if (dispatcherTimer.Interval > span)
            {
                Hello.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
                dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            }
        };
```

But button keeps fade in and fade out.
i want color to be constant

### C#

```
            private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Hello.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue;
        var dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(61);
        TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0,1,0);
        dispatcherTimer.Start(); 
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += delegate
        {

            if (dispatcherTimer.Interval > span)
            {
                Hello.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
                dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            }
        };


    }
```

### Xaml

```
<Button Name="Hello" Content="Hello" Background="White"  Foreground="Black " Click="Button_Click">
 </Button>
```

Comment: We're missing some code here. Is this part of a method that is being fired from a timer?  Show the whole method.

Comment: What do you mean "fade in fade out" ? What are you using? MVVM? Code behind? How/Where is your button defined?

Comment: Guys I have added my C# and xaml code. By Fade In fade out i mean that after tick the red color is getting dim and then back and back

Answer (score 4):

You could just create a `Style` and use a `Trigger` to start a `Storyboard` with `ColorAnimations`

Example:

```
<Style x:Key="AnimatedButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color">
                        <ColorAnimation To="Blue" Duration="0:0:4" />
                        <ColorAnimation To="Red" BeginTime="0:1:52" Duration="0:0:4" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tried it now ..... however this is code behind

**XAML Code:**

```
   <Button  Content="Button"  x:Name="MyButton" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="94,128,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

**Cs File**

```
    private void StartAnimation()
    {

        Color fromRGB= Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255); ;
        Color ToRGB= Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0);

        SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        myBrush.Color = Colors.Black;
        ColorAnimation myAnimation = new ColorAnimation();
        myAnimation.From = fromRGB;
        myAnimation.To = ToRGB;
        myAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(120000));
        myAnimation.AutoReverse = true;

        myBrush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, myAnimation );

        MyButton.Background = myBrush;
    }
```

you can change the color when your event is called and then call your animation.

Comment: Hmm ... love the solution using animations, but this will just slowly go from one color to the other and back ... I thought the user wants a color when clicked, and after 2 minutes, bam, different one ... (I think, since he wasn't very specific :)

Comment: Yes it came to my mind after posting the answer :)..The OP can modify the way he wants

Answer (score 0):

could you try to use a simple StoryBoard created in Blend and then apply to Button/style
something like this:

```
<Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" >
        <Button.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="MySolidColorBrush" Color="Brown" />
        </Button.Background>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                            From="Red" To="Yellow" Duration="0:0:0" RepeatBehavior="1x"  />
                        <ColorAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="MySolidColorBrush"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                            From="Yellow" To="Blue" Duration="0:0:0" RepeatBehavior="1x" BeginTime="0:0:10"  />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

Comment: key is BeginTime of second animation, which in your case would be 2minutes

Answer (score 0):

Just to show a different approach really ... If you're using MVVM, you could bind your button color to a property on the ViewModel, and once you click on it, run your 2 minutes background/timer . Once the 2 minutes are done, it'll change the color to the other one.

Not much xaml involved, and I do like some of the other solutions here :)

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000); // two second
        ButtonColorPropertyName= Colors.Red;
}
```

(Assuming you have the `ButtonColorPropertyName` or whatever you want to name it, in the ViewModel)

Comment: Would you not need to dispatch the line "Prop = Colors.Red" to the Gui-thread?

Comment: Nope ... that's the beauty of it ... the view model doesn't even know about the view. for all it cares, he knows that two seconds after the click, he changes the color. The view binds to that property, and that's how the magic works :)